# Add space after each token in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
char str[] = "01 21 03 06   0f 1a 1c 33   3a 3b";
char *pch;
char *m[100];
pch = strtok (str,"' ''  '");
size_t i = 0;
while (pch !=NULL)
{
m[i]=pch;
i++;
pch = strtok (NULL,"' ''  '");
}
for (int j=0;j!=i;j++)
{
 printf("%s",m[j]);

}
return 0;
```

I want to add space after each token. I want to include space as part of array m. Not the printf(" ") before `printf("%s",m[j]);` I am getting out put as "012103060f1a1c333a3b"how do i add space after each 2 characters?

Comment: `if (j!=0) { printf(" "); }` just before your `printf("%s,...)?

Comment: hey i want to include space as the part of array m not for only printing values in the console

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite in C++ to make it much more simple:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::string str("01 21 03 06   0f 1a 1c 33   3a 3b");
  std::vector<std::string> m;
  std::istringstream inp(str);
  std::string token;
  while (inp >> token)
  {
    std::ostringstream outp;
    outp << token << " ";
    m.push_back(outp.str());
  }
  for (const auto& tok: m) { std::cout << tok; }
}
```

When using `stringstream`, you can just read in tokens separated by any whitespace and stream them to an outputstream in the desired format.

Remark that using the outputstream is more generic than really needed here.  It can be replaced with `m.push_back(token + " ");`